# How to attach same handler to multiple events but call only once when both events are triggered simultaneously

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I am writing a wrapper for material-ui/AutoComplete.
I want it to:

1. set value and submit on clicking the suggestions,
2. set value and submit on pressing enter on the suggestions,
3. navigate through list by pressing arrow keys
4. submit on clicking a submit button next to the AutoComplete button.

I realise that I need to capture three events:

- onKeyDownCapture
- onKeyDown
- onNewRequest

All the events are handled using the same handler.

Among these events, onNewRequest is triggered as usual but onKeyDown is triggered when I press the enter button while onKeyDownCapture captures a click.
When the value updates, the component also triggers onNewRequest automatically, leading to duplicate and expensive calls to my search service.

Is there a way to block duplicate calls for search service?

Here is the code for my component:

```
handler(){
// calls search service.
}

render(){
return (
      <AutoComplete
        ...{props}
        onKeyDownCapture={this.handler}
        onKeyDown={this.handler}
        onNewRequest={this.handler}
      />
}
```

I tried an ugly "newRequestDuplicatesHandler" which basically keeps track of the last search request text and prevents the duplicate requests by comparing the new search request text. However this is not a clean solution.

The original code, as shown above causes duplicate requests.

However, the newRequestDuplicatesHandler does the trick. But this is not a clean solution.

Comment: Did you need to trigger the onKeyDown using enter key?

Comment: Add a delay before dispatching the network call. Cancel the previous promise if the new event data is not similar as old(i.e., previous promise)